# Google APi client opens popup instead of redirect

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth

I am creating google oauth2 client for the first time and I need to redirect to google account page, and after log in, redirect back to my app.

I configure gapi client like this but always open popup:

```
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: 'xxxxxx',
                scope: 'profile email',
                ux_mode: 'redirect',
                redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/login.html'
            });
```

Can you tell me how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: im not sure i understand the issue its going to popup and request access.

Comment: @DaImTo hi, thank you for effort. I show my gapi configuration. It works, but with popup window where I choose google acc or login. Instead popup I would like to have redirect to google server and then redirect back to my app. I tried configure it but doesn't work, I have still popup.

Comment: You can not change the internal function of Google's Authentication server.  If you have multiple google accounts on your machine it will first pop up and ask you to choose an account, after that it will ask the user to consent to your access, once that is done if you have properly set the javascript origin it will redirect to the user or you will get a redirect uri error message.   This is how it works you cant change things.

Comment: @DaImTo so why is there ux_mode: 'redirect' option? In docs is written that is for this case - choose if I prefer redirect or popup

Comment: I am also facing the same issue @DenisStephanov. Did you find any solution yet?